# Using Promise.all on an array of objects to get data with axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have an array of object that looks like

```js
[{url, personName}, {url, personName}]
```

I want it so that I am doing a concurrent call on all the URL endpoints but I also want to keep track of the personName that is associated to the URL. I know that if this was an array of URLs I could just use Promise.all on the array. But how do I do it on an array of objects where I only want to call it on the URL key.

Comment: What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?  Have you tried looping over the array, invoking your AJAX operation, and adding that Promise to a resulting array?  (e.g. Using `.map()` on the source array and returning the `Promise` for each callback.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `.map` to extract and fetch all URLs. Since the order of responses is preserved when using `Promise.all` you can just access the original name by its index. Something like this should work:

```js
const data = [
  { url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/1", name: 'George' },
  { url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/2", name: 'Janet' },
];

(async() => {
  
  // extract just the urls into an array
  const urls = data.map(({ url }) => url);
  
  // make a request to each url
  const promises = urls.map(axios.get);
  
  // await each response
  const responses = await Promise.all(promises);
  
  // combine each response with its associated name 
  const results = responses.map((response, index) => ({
      name: data[index].name, // find the original name by its index
      data: response.data
  }));
  
  console.log(results);
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

You can also do this in one go:

```js
const data = [
  { url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/1", name: 'George' },
  { url: "https://reqres.in/api/users/2", name: 'Janet' },
];

(async() => {

  const results = await Promise.all(data.map(async({ url, name }) => ({
      name,
      data: (await axios.get(url)).data
  })));

  console.log(results);

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.4.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```